# In python, what does len(list) do?

Tags: python, list

Does `len(list)` calculate the length of the list every time it is called, or does it return the value of the built-in counter?
I have a context where I need to check the length of a list every time through a loop, like:

```
listData = []
for value in ioread():
    if len(listData)>=25:
        processlistdata()
        clearlistdata()
    listData.append(value)
```

Should I check `len(listData)` on every iteration, or should I have a counter for the length of the list?

Comment: I am 99.9% positive that any sequence type in higher-level languages will store its length. The `len` (or `strlen` or `length`) functions in Python, Perl, and Ruby (and other such languages) should never take O(N) time.

Comment: I'd replace your code by `for chunk in grouper(ioread(), 25): process(chunk)` Where `grouper()` is defined similar to http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes (you might like to replace `izip_longest()` by `izip()` to drop last values as your code does).

Comment: Did you measure the two versions to see which one is actually faster?  It's easier to use `timeit` and post your results so we can comment on them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should probably be aware, if you're worried about this operation's performance, that "lists" in Python [are really](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/101848-list-implementation) dynamic arrays. That is, they're not implemented as linked lists, which you generally have to "walk" to compute a length for (unless stored in a header).

Since they already need to store "bookkeeping" information to handle memory allocation, the length is stored too.

Answer (score 2):

```
Help on built-in function len in module __builtin__:

len(...)
    len(object) -> integer

    Return the number of items of a sequence or mapping.
```

so yes, `len(list)` returns how many items in the list. You might want to describe in more details, providing necessary input files/output to help better understand what you want to do.

Comment: The OP is worried about whether this length will be recalculated every time it's asked for.

Answer (score 0):

`len(list)` returns the length of a list. If you change it, you'll have to check it's length every iteration. Or use a counter.

Answer (score 0):

len(list) returns the length of the list. Everytime you call it, it will return the length of the list as it currently is. You could set up a counter by taking the len of list initially and then adding 1 to the variable each time something is appended to the list.