# What does the ```len``` keyword do and its definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have found this program which involves the **`len`** keyword.

```
def split_list(orig_list):
    list_len = len(orig_list)
    mid_pos = math.ceil(list_len/2)
    list1 = orig_list[:mid_pos]
    list2 = orig_list[mid_pos:]
    return [list1,list2]
def main():
    colors = ['red','blue','green','orange','purple']
    colors_split = split_list(colors)
    print(colors_split[0])
    print(colors_split[1])
main()
```

the **`len`** keyword is found in line 2 of this program.

**This is what I have researched about the `len` keyword**

```
list1, list2 = [123, 'xyz', 'zara'], [456, 'abc']
print "First list length : ", len(list1)
print "Second list length : ", len(list2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python, what does len(list) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399835/in-python-what-does-lenlist-do)

Comment: It does not, I just want to find out plainly what does the ```len``` keyword do and its definition

Comment: In that case, looking at the documentation should always be your first step, like @juleslasne suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

```
Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).
```